# Angular 7 : Use different background + hover color for each tabs

Tags: angular, tabs, angular7, ngbtab

I am working on Angular 7. For tab I have used [Tabset](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/api). I want to use different colors for each tabs for background and hover effect both.

Here is code:

```
 <div class="card-body md-tabs">
<ngb-tabset (tabChange)="fun($event.nextId)">
  <ngb-tab id="BasicInfo" style="color: #004d40 !important;">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle class="tab-title tab">
      <span style="color: #004d40;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;"><i
          class="icofont icofont-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Basic Information</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <div [@fadeInOutTranslate] class="m-t-15">

      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab style="background-color: red" id="Supplier">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle><span style="color: #e65100;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;"><i
          class="fa fa-money"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Supplier</span></ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <div [@fadeInOutTranslate] class="m-t-15">

      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab style="background-color: red" id="Tax">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle><span style="color: #e65100;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;"><i
          class="fa fa-money"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tax</span></ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <div [@fadeInOutTranslate] class="m-t-15">

      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab id="Terms">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      <span style="color: #1a237e;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;"><i
          class="fa fa-book"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Terms</span>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <div [@fadeInOutTranslate] class="m-t-15">

      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab id="Misc">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      <span style="color: #bf360c;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;"><i
          class="fa fa-file-text"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Miscellaneous</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <div [@fadeInOutTranslate] class="m-t-15">

      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab id="Graph">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      <span style="color: #01579b;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;">
        <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Graph View
      </span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <div [@fadeInOutTranslate] class="m-t-15">

      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
</div>
```

[image]

Is there any way? Anyone can help for this?

Comment: `/deep/ md-tab-item .md-tab:first-child {
 background: red;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label:first-child  {
  color:red;
  background-color: green;
}

::ng-deep .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label:first-child:hover  {
  color:green;
  background-color: red;
}
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jggy2s

Comment: @PratikButaniAndroidDev I have posted a working example. Please check it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmxerq

Comment: I have pasted some code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsx9cx) In that `md-tab` is not applying. You can check and change.

Comment: Do you want to change ngb-tab to md-tab? Or do you want different color for different ngb-tab. As per your question  you want to use different colors for each tabs (ngb-tabs) for background and hover.

Comment: I mean `md-tab` is not applying in `stackblits`

Comment: The recent version of Material use mat-tab. Are you open to use mat-tab? Or you need to use md-tab only?

Comment: Didn't get actual answer but your efforts are enough to get bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Mouseenter, mouseleave.
Here is a simple and basic example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obcut6

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a little more specific of what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Sounds to me like an encapsulation issue, try moving your styles to the global styles.scss file or add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your host component's metadata (the component that has the tabs in its template)

Comment: @PratikButani Can you create a stackblitz so I can try it too?
because the only reason it won't work this way is that your CSS selector isn't correct

Comment: I have pasted some code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tsx9cx) In that `md-tab` is not applying. You can check and change.